# Updating Label on UI from within a Thread

Tags: c#

What's the conventional way to update a UI from within a thread?

For example I have a method within a class that handles a users login. Within this method I would like to provide feedback to the user at various stages of the login processes in the form of a label on the UI (main thread).

```
public void userLogin(User _user)
{
    // 1. Navigate to site.com
    // 2. Update label on UI
    // 3. Attempt login
    // 4. Update label on UI
    // 5. Check login status
    // 6. Update label on UI
}
```

I don't want to include the code to update the UI within the method because the class itself is used in other projects, and by other team members on different projects. In some projects rather than update a label on the UI I might decide to save it to a log file for debugging. I don't want to create any form of coupling.

What's the best solution? Would Events be the way to go?

Btw. I'm using .NET 4.5 and C# 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that following the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and using an event would be your best option.  It's really what they are designed to be used for.

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. I was thinking about this pattern some days ago and couldn't think of the name of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms you can use [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) class.